# TypeError : cannot read property 'input' of null

Tags: angular

I was trying to install angular, I installed Node then angular
and when i try to get the version of angular using this command line : `ng --version`, I get this error :
`TypeError : Cannot read property 'input'  of null`

I've also installed angular using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Angular Globally using the cli and?

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```